# Routing Chat with Omni Channel

Tags: liveagent, omnichannel

We use omni channel to route the chats and we create case for each chat session in the pre-chat page . When the chat is routed to agent , to the right of chat transcript layout we see a column with messages saying "Account is not linked" , "No Lead is linked" etc . How do we remove those?

Comment: Hey. Can you provide a screenshot of what you are encountering.